# Trying to establish a connection with SQL Server 2008

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008

```
SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection();
cnn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=.;Database = deptStore;Integrated Security = true;";

cnn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "insert into Employee values('" + TextBox1.Text + "','" + TextBox2.Text + "','" + TextBox3.Text + "','" + TextBox4.Text + "','" + TextBox5.Text + "','" + TextBox6.Text + "','" + TextBox7.Text + "','" + TextBox8.Text + "','" + TextBox9.Text + "','" + TextBox10.Text + "','" + TextBox11.Text + "','" + TextBox12.Text + "','" + TextBox13.Text + "')";
cmd.Connection = cnn;

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Response.Write("Record Save");
cnn.Close();
```

But I am getting following error:

> *SqlException was unhandled by user code*
>
> *A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)*

Kindly help me to understand the error and rectify it.

Comment: I voted to close this question -- many people gave solutions and all you do is say "not working".  You have to engage and read the answers and respond to their answers.  **WE WILL NOT BE ABLE TO FIX THIS PROBLEM IF ALL YOU DO IS COPY A CONNECTION STRING AND REPORT IT DOES NOT WORK**

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified that SQL Server is configured correctly? You can do this by opening the SQL Server Configuration Tool.

If you're connecting to SQL Server Express then you need to specify the name of the instance which is always `SQLExpress` in the connection string.

I.e

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS"...
```

Answer (score 0):

First check your webconfig. There should be a code like this

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ConnStringDb1" connectionString="Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=deptStore;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

or if you want just replace YourDataBaseName.
Next is to set up your connection

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnStringDb1"].ToString());
```

And thats it, you have a connection string

You need to read more about this cause I also see that your Insert Query is wrong

try This

**cnn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Database=deptStore;Integrated Security=true;";**

Comment: @user1716251 do you know how to establish connection?